May I find $\zeta(-1)$ using the Hankel formula for $\zeta$, but not the reflection formula?
The Reimann zeta function for $\Re(s) > 1$ is
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s},$$
and we may show that the analytic continuation of $\zeta$ onto $\Re(s) \leq 1, s \neq 1$ is
$$\zeta(s) = \frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{-t}-1} dt $$
where $C$ is the Hankel countour in the left-hand side of the complex plane, and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.
So, theoretically, I could evaluate $\zeta(-1)$ from this formula, right?
Perhaps an easier way of evaluating $\zeta(-1)$ is using the reflection formula
$$\zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin (\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)$$
and plugging in $s=-1$. However, the way this formula is derived (or at least, how I've seen it be derived) is by using the Hankel contour. We may take the Hankel contour for $\Re(t) > -N$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and enclose the whole thing in an almost-rectangle with sides at $\Re(t) = \pm N$, $\Im(t) = \pm(N+\frac{1}{2})$. We may show that the integral vanishes as $N \to \infty$ on the rectangle, evaluate the residues, do some algebra and get the reflection formula $\zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin (\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)$.
But what if I instead just put $s=-1$ into the Hankel formula?
$$\zeta(-1) = \frac{\Gamma(2)}{2 \pi i} \int_C \underbrace{\frac{t^{-2}}{e^{-t}-1}}_{f(t)} dt,$$
so in particular $2 \pi i \zeta(-1) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\gamma_+} f(t) dt + \int_{\gamma_-} f(t) dt + \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} f(t) dt$,
where $\gamma_{\pm}: t = xe^{\pm i \pi}$, $x \in (\epsilon, \infty)$, $\gamma_{\epsilon}: t = \epsilon e^{i \theta}$, $\theta \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.
I'm then a bit stuck, as this is going to require the evaluation of
$$I_{\pm} = \int_{\gamma_{\pm}} \frac{x^{-2} e^{\pm 2 \pi i }}{e^{x 
 e^{\pm i \pi}}-1} dx = \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2} e^{\pm 2 \pi i }}{e^{x}-1} dx.$$
But, for one, finding the value of $\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2}}{e^{x}-1} dx$ seems pretty tricky. And for two, $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2}}{e^{x}-1} dx = \infty$. $I_+$ and $I_-$ don't even cancel each other out in a principal-value type of way, as $I_+ + I_- = 2 \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2}}{e^{x}-1} dx \cos(2 \pi)$, and the contribution from $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ doesn't seem to help to resolve this.
Am I just doing something wrong here, or can I not really use $\zeta(s) = \frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{-t}-1} dt$ to evaluate $\zeta(-1)$, in an algebraic sense?
Of course, we could essentially follow the steps deriving the reflection formula but just with $s=-1$. But I'm wondering if there's something more direct and procedural that can be done here.

$\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ can also be evaluated using globally convergent series such as $$\zeta (s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}, \underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^K \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^s} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{K-n} \binom{K+1}{j}\right)\tag{1}$$ evaluated as $s=-1$. Formula (1) above evaluates exactly correct at $s=-1$ for all $K\ge 1$.

Define $g(z):= \frac{e^{-z}-1}{z}$ for $z\neq 0$ and $g(0):= -1$. Then $g$ is an entire function, because $g(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}$. Define $h := \frac{1}{g}$. It is
$$\zeta(-1) = \frac{\Gamma(2)}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{z^{-2}}{e^{-z}-1} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{h(z)}{z^3}dz.$$
By Cauchy's Theorem and the fact, that $h$ is holomorphic in the strip $\{|\Im(z)| < 2\pi\}$, it follows
$$\int_C \frac{h(z)}{z^3}dz = \int_{|z|=1} \frac{h(z)}{z^3}dz = \frac{2\pi i}{2!}\frac{d^2 h}{dz^2}(0)$$
Now
$$\frac{d^2 h}{dz^2} = \frac{d}{dz}\left(-\frac{g'}{g^2}\right) = -\frac{g''}{g^2}+2\frac{(g')^2}{g^3}$$
By power series of $g$ it is $g'(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n \frac{z^{n-1}}{(n+1)!}$ and $g''(z) = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n(n-1) \frac{z^{n-2}}{(n+1)!}$ and therefore $g'(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $g''(0) = -\frac{1}{3}$, thus
$$\frac{d^2 h}{dz^2}(0) = -\frac{-1/3}{(-1)^2}+2\frac{(1/2)^2}{(-1)^3} = \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{6}$$
It follows
$$\zeta(-1) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{h(z)}{z^3}dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\cdot \frac{2\pi i}{2!}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right) = -\frac{1}{12}.$$
